# hp pro liant ml370 g4 not booting to lubuntu login screen

Tags: boot, lubuntu, hp

I'm having trouble booting my Proliant (ml370 g4) to the Lubuntu login screen. It appears to boot properly but when it gets to the point where it should go to the login screen it doesn't. I've used three different monitors (Mag Innovision 700p, ViewSonic VX910, and a Samsung s22b150n.) but none of them work. They say: no signal, out of range, and not optimum mode recommended mode 1920x1080, respectively. and ether the message stays there or it cuts to black. Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: You've not provided any release details.  *I'm also not sure what you mean by home screen; do you mean greeter (ie. `sddm` or login screen), the desktop display? the lxqt menu? lxqt-panel? or what  exactly*

Comment: My apologize, I am fairly new to computers; specifically software. What I mean by home screen is the login screen.

Comment: That still doesn't really clarify things, as we don't know your release. I assume you mean the `sddm` greeter isn't appearing (if you're using a different release to the range I'm assuming though; it'll be something else; release detail we should be provided).

Comment: it should be Lubuntu-18.04

Comment: FYI: Are you aware that flavors of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that is now EOL (*end-of-life*).  See https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/  https://lubuntu.me/bionic-5-released/ https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/  with support ending April-2021.   Use `ubuntu-support-status` on your system to confirm the supported/unsupported packages & act accordingly (ie. how important is security to you, are you offline etc?)